# Is there another approach to a huge list of dictionaries of lists for iOS Swift 2? -Xcode stuck at indexing

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm new to Swift 2 Language and I came from Python. I have this structure for a mobile app project:

```
var college = ["Bachelor of Science in Computer Science":
                ["First Year":
                  ["First Semester": [
                      "Course Code": [<values>],
                      "Course Description": [<values>],
                      "Course Units": [<values>]
                      ],  // End of First Semester
                   "Second Semester": [
                      "Course Code": [<values>],
                      "Course Description": [<values],
                      "Course Units": [<values>]
                      ]   // End of Second Semester
                  ],  // End of First Year
                 // Continue up to Fourth Year (Fifth Year if there's any)
                 // Continue to next Degree for the current college
              ]  // End of variable
```

Apparently, Xcode seems to be stuck in indexing forever and none of the answers around works for me. If I remove this particular variable, the app will load just fine. Is there another workaround for this?

Info that might help:
The structure works fine in Python but it doesn't work with Swift when the data gets bigger. The nested dictionaries of lists works when the data structure is still small.

Comment: Do you have a typo in this line? "Course Description": [<values]?  Should it be "Course Description": [<values>],

Comment: Is there any reason you would want to use nested dictionaries over concrete structures? It looks like you have a lot of similar nested items that could be turned into a struct.

Comment: @Dave2e sorry for that one, `values` is just a placeholder there.

Comment: @KennethBruno Aside from being new to this language (I have little knowledge on what Swift can do), none. Since the syntax was quite similar to Python for dictionaries, gave it a shot. Didn't get what I expected.

Comment: Of course you can do this kind of structure in Swift but it may not be an optimal representation for data. Not to mention that Swift is a young language and some areas may not be as optimized as Python. Take a look at my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be seeing Swift struggle to infer a type signature for this data structure. Specifying one can dramatically improve your compile/index times, e.g.

`var college: [String: [String: [String: [String: [type_of_values]]]]] = ["Bachelor of Science in Computer Science":...`

As is the compiler has to inspect all of those values to try to determine what the most specific available type common to all of them is.

You might also find it useful to define a set of domain models here so you're not just working with string keys. That would probably also resolve your compiler performance problem.

Comment: Had lots of variable with the said structure above already and this was the quickest workaround. Works now and compiles faster, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use a set of structs for your data and if you need to you can serialize and deserialize it into some other format such as JSON.

The advantages are speed, size, ease of programming (you get warnings for incorrect types and structure, plus autofilled parameters), readability, and flexibility.

```
struct Course {
  let code:String
  let description:String
  let units:String
}

enum Order {
  case First
  case Second
  case Third
  case Fourth
  case Fifth
  case Sixth
}

struct Semester {
  let order:Order
  let courses:[Course]
}

struct Year {
  let order:Order
  let semesters:[Semester]
}

struct Degree {
  let name:String
  let years:[Year]
}

let college = Degree(name: "Bachelor of Science in Computer Science",
  years: [
    Year(order: .First, semesters: [
      Semester(order: .First, courses: [
        Course(code: "CS101", description: "Some course.", units: "123"),
        Course(code: "CS102", description: "Some course.", units: "123")]),
      Semester(order: .Second, courses: [
        Course(code: "CS201", description: "Some course.", units: "123"),
        Course(code: "CS202", description: "Some course.", units: "123")])]),
    Year(order: .Second, semesters: [])]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an alternative, this works and is more organized than the approach I tried but I needed a quick workaround since deadline is fast approaching and I already have a lot of variables containing the structure above so rewriting it again would be time consuming. I regret not asking for another approach first before diving into the approach I used. I only realized this problem when I noticed it won't stop indexing which was too late already. Will use this next time I encounter another problem like this. Thanks.